# How do I create a ToggleButton via code?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

How do I create a `ToggleButton` via code? I tried using `ButtonGroup`. Using a `CheckBox` works, but `TextButton` does not:

```
...
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("one", skin);
CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox("two", skin);
CheckBox checkBox3 = new CheckBox("three", skin);

ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup(checkBox, checkBox2, checkBox3);
...

...
TextButton playButton = new TextButton("one", skin);
TextButton playButton2 = new TextButton("two", skin);
TextButton playButton3 = new TextButton("three", skin);

ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup(playButton, playButton2, playButton3);
```

I found this example, but I still can not adjust the background:

```
TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
textButtonStyle.font = someBitmapFont;
textButtonStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
textButtonStyle.downFontColor = Color.BLACK;
//Optional color to toggle between when pressed
textButtonStyle.checkedFontColor = Color.GREEN;
final TextButton textButton = new TextButton("Text", textButtonStyle);
final TextButton textButton2 = new TextButton("Text", textButtonStyle);
final TextButton textButton3 = new TextButton("Text", textButtonStyle);

ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup(textButton, textButton2,textButton3);
```

On the left is what I am left with; on the right is what I want.

[image] [image]

Here is my current code:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round },
    toggle: { down: default-round-down, checked: default-round-down, up: default-round }
},

com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { 
        down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font, fontColor: white 
    },
    toggle: { 
        down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-round-down, 
            font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red 
    }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [javadocs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html) of the `Button` class:

> Each time a button is clicked, the checked state is toggled.

So the buttons are probably checked, you just can't see it. The reason for not being able to see it might be that your `Skin` (or `ButtonStyle`) does not contain a drawable for the `checked` state. This means that the button will not show when it is actually checked. If you want to double-check if your buttons are checked you can call `Button#isChecked()` and see what value it returns.

Also, if you want to make your buttons act as radio buttons (i.e. only one can be toggled at a time) you want to set `ButtonGroup#setMaxCheckedCount(count)` and `ButtonGroup#setMinCheckedCount(count)` both to 1 so that no more or no less than one button can be toggled at a time.

**Update**: to use your "toggle" style from your skin do this:

```
new TextButton("text", skin, "toggle");
```